# deleting multiple files From FTP

Tags: batch-file, ftp

Is there any way to delete all files From FTP. i'm able to delete single files,but not able to delete all the files.I've tried below script but not working for multiple files.

```
ftp
open <SERVER>
<Usename>
<Pass>
cd </file_location>
delete *.xlsx`
 bye
```

"It's showing Error,No such(*.xls files)".
If I use delete File_Name then it's working.I've also tried mdelete and rm. Please help  me how can i delete all the files with .xlsx extension.

Comment: `mdelete` should work.  I do see a discrepancy in your description.  Your code is trying to delete all `XLSX` files but the error you are showing us says it is trying to delete all `XLS` files.

Comment: There's also that ` at the end of the delete line, but I think that was a typo made while pasting the code here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.after adding prompt,it's working fine.@Squashman,  it was (*.xlsx files),@SomethingDark ,yes it was type made while pasting the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mdelete` would have worked if you disabled prompting first.

```
ftp
open <SERVER>
<Usename>
<Pass>
cd </file_location>
prompt
mdel *.xlsx
bye
```

Comment: Another option is to use the -I option when executing ftp.exe.